# MYSQL UPDATE WITH DATE_ADD

Tags: mysql, sql-update, dateadd

I am trying to set a cron to update a status if a date has passed a value in the DB.

```
$q="UPDATE posts SET post_status = 3 
WHERE DATE_ADD(post_date, INTERVAL post_duration DAY) < CURDATE()
";
```

Does not return anything run against phpmyadmin but

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE DATE_ADD(post_date, INTERVAL post_duration DAY) < CURDATE( )
```

works fine?  Am I missing something here

Comment: Are you asking if your `update` statement should return rows?  If so, no it won't.  If that `select` statement returns data, then the `update` statement should update those records to `post_status = 3`...

Comment: Select works and Update has no results returned?

Comment: running against phpmyadmin an UPDATE usually returns "x rows effected".  Mine is returning "0 rows effected"  even though testing with the SELECT show over 120 rows that meet the criteria?

Comment: My mistake, it did work but when running the SELECT I needed to rule out the rows already updated to 3.  It was showing me the ones already updated.  Dumb of me...